# Write exception in text file application path

Tags: vb.net, logging

I would like to catch exceptions to my application startup path in a file called "`log_errors`" and new exceptions on a new line, instead of `messagebox.show`:

```
Try
    Dim t As Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf MySub))
    _runningThreads.Add(t)
    t.Start()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at some Logging Utils such as: https://nlog-project.org/

Comment: and, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Answering your specific question, for a very basic logging feature:

Create a "logging" Sub and pass the message to it:

```
Public Sub LogToFile(ByVal strMessage as String)

  ' Will create a log_errors.txt file if it doesn't already exist; otherwise, appends to it.
  File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\log_errors.txt", strMessage)

End Sub
```

Then in your `Catch ex As Exception`, instead of:

`MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`

do

`LogToFile(ex.Message)`